# What does "still" mean here?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, adverbs

> How fast should you read? The
>   answer depends on what you are reading. Sometimes you need to read things
>   slowly and carefully. At other times, you can read quickly, and **at still other
>   times**, you can read at an average speed.

The adverb *still* has at least [three senses](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/still#cald4-1-1-2). What does it mean here? Has it been written in a normal place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the meaning of "still" in the text you quoted. It is in the correct place.

> still adverb (GREATER DEGREE)
>    ​ B2 to an even greater degree or in an
>   even greater amount:

[Still](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/still)

Comment: In the example, hasn't the writer sort of dramatized it? I mean it is not something extraordinary: Sometimes A, at other times B, and at other times C. Is there any point in the emphasis?

Comment: What is being emphasised is not some special quality of the third possibility, rather, the multiplicity of possibilities (greater than two).